# generate date range to be used in a loop

Tags: python

I need to generate dates between 17 Sep to 18 October in the mm_dd format. What I did is to use 2 separate loops like this...

sep 17 to 30 data # 09_17 to 09_30

```
for i in range(17, 31):
    receiver=x.runQuery("copy  dlr_2014_198_bk_todel from 'http://www/sms_sending18.179.67.198_2015_09_"+str(i).zfill(2)+"_utf.csv.gz' CREDENTIALS delimiter '\t' emptyasnull escape gzip")
```

Oct 1 to 18 data # 10_01 to 10_18

```
for i in range(1, 19):
    receiver=x.runQuery("copy  dlr_2014_198_bk_todel from 'http://www/sms_sending18.179.67.198_2015_10_"+str(i).zfill(2)+"_utf.csv.gz' CREDENTIALS delimiter '\t' emptyasnull escape gzip")
```

Is it possible to use a single loop for this? (Date range may be of a few days or a few years) How do I dynamically generate dates in the format 2015_09_17 those can be used in the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `datetime` module to format a string with `str.format()`:

```
d = datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 17)
for i in range(33):
    d += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    receiver=x.runQuery("copy  dlr_2014_198_bk_todel from 'http://www/sms_sending18.179.67.198_{}_utf.csv.gz' CREDENTIALS delimiter '\t' emptyasnull escape gzip".format(datetime.datetime.strftime(d, '%Y_%m_%d))
```

Replacing the query with a `print()`:

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 17)
>>> for i in range(33):
...     d += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
...     print("copy  dlr_2014_198_bk_todel from 'http://www/sms_sending18.179.67.198_{}_utf.csv.gz' CREDENTIALS delimiter '\t' emptyasnull escape gzip".format(datetime.datetime.strftime(d, '%Y_%m_%d')))
...
copy  dlr_2014_198_bk_todel from 'http://www/sms_sending18.179.67.198_2015_09_18_utf.csv.gz' CREDENTIALS delimiter '    ' emptyasnull escape gzip
copy  dlr_2014_198_bk_todel from 'http://www/sms_sending18.179.67.198_2015_09_19_utf.csv.gz' CREDENTIALS delimiter '    ' emptyasnull escape gzip

(snip)

copy  dlr_2014_198_bk_todel from 'http://www/sms_sending18.179.67.198_2015_10_19_utf.csv.gz' CREDENTIALS delimiter '    ' emptyasnull escape gzip
copy  dlr_2014_198_bk_todel from 'http://www/sms_sending18.179.67.198_2015_10_20_utf.csv.gz' CREDENTIALS delimiter '    ' emptyasnull escape gzip
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use datetime and timedelta. The loop increments the start date by one day until the end date is reached.

Advantage: Variable month lengths are handled automatically.

```
#!/bin/python
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


start = datetime(2015,9,17)
end = datetime(2015,10,18)
step = timedelta(days=1)
while start <= end:
    print start.strftime('%Y_%m_%d')
    start += step
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_date = date(2015, 9, 17) 
end_date = date(2015, 10, 18)

for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    print single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

For inclusive iteration use the next day, as you are using with range().

Answer (score 1):

you could also use [dateutil](https://labix.org/python-dateutil). the dateutil.rrule set has the functions you need

```
from dateutil.rrule import rrule
from datetime import datetime

format = '%d_%m'
start = datetime(2015,10,8) 
end = datetime(2015,11,8)

mydates = rrule(DAILY, dtstart = start, until = end)
for myday in mydates.count():
    print mydates[i].strftime(format)
```

you could add more conditions to the rrule, like settinga monthly or weekly recurrence, skipping certain days of the week, returing every other day, etc.

e.g.

```
rrule(WEEKLY, byweekday(MO,TU), interval = 2 dtstart = start, until = end)
```

will give you every the monday and tuesday of every other week between start and end.